# How to prevent infinite re-rendering with useEffect() in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I am new for development.I have created a chat application using socket io.I have the useEffect change only when socket changes, but I have setMessage in the body of useEffect() meaning update the message and I put the socket as dependency.But this doesn't work and it re-runs infinitum.

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';

function Chat({socket,username,room}) {
    const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState("");
    const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);
    const sendMessage = async () => {
        if (currentMessage !== "") {
            const messageData = {
                room: room,
                author: username,
                message: currentMessage,
                time: new Date(Date.now()).getHours()
                    + ':' +
                    new Date(Date.now()).getMinutes()
            };
            await socket.emit("send_message", messageData);
            sendMessage((list)=>[...list,messageData]);
            
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
          setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
          setCurrentMessage("");
          
        });
      }, [socket]);
    return (
        <div className='chat-window'>
            <div className='chat-header'>
                <p>Live Chat</p>
            </div>
            <div className='chat-body'>
                <ScrollToBottom className='message-container'>
                {messageList.map((messageContent)=>{
                    return (
                    <div className='message' id={username===messageContent.author?"you":"other"}>
                       <h1>{messageContent.message}</h1>
                    </div>
                    );
                
                    })}
                </ScrollToBottom>

            </div>
            <div className='chat-footer'>
                <input type="text" value={currentMessage}placeholder='Hey..' onChange={(event) => {
                    setCurrentMessage(event.target.value);
                }} 
                onKeyPress={(event)=>{
                    event.key==='Enter'&&sendMessage();
                }}/>
                <button onClick={sendMessage}>&#9658;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Chat;
```

How to stop rendering the useEffect function?

Comment: How do you know it's the `useEffect` that is causing the re-rendering?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you don't have to pass socket as a dependency.

Test this snippet and let me know if it's working.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
     setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
     setCurrentMessage("");        
  });
  
  return () => {
     socket.off('receive_message');
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: I've read some examples on the internet.
They all use this pattern, I think there's problem in your server.

Comment: May u read this blog ? 

https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `socket` as a dependency of the effect.

Comment: Much welcome dude.
Can u vote this as a useful answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recursion happening in **sendMessage** Function, which is causing an infinite loop.

Removing the below line may fix the issue

```
sendMessage((list)=>[...list,messageData]);
```

Also, don't forget to remove the **socket** from the dependency array.

Comment: Having `socket` in the dependency array of the effect is totally fine

Comment: removing the above, results in, not depicting the message in the author chat. I have to include what author is saying in author's chat.

Comment: you are using sendMessage in sendMessage, I think it's a mistake because I believe this recursion is causing an infinite loop because there is no stopping condition.
maybe you wanted to write setMessageList in the sendMessage function.

Comment: Yes sir!! You are right. I had written wrong, instead of setMessageList I wrote sendMessage. Now am getting two outputs which can be resolved by using dependency in useEffect(generally), but in this case, it isn't working. I have this issue now!!!

Comment: @RobertDowneyJr. You should also add the UID attribute and while setting the list in useEffect, filter out the list based on UID so it can be shown as one

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have ran into this problem recently, however there's some options that you can try:

1. **Add listener in the file where socket is initialized**

Instead of passing socket into child component, you should only pass the data to the child component

example `index.js`:

```
const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);

// Do not use any deps here
useEffect(() => {
   let socket = init() // or something

   socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
      setCurrentMessage("");
   });
}, [])

return (
    <ChildComponent messageList={messageList} />
)
```

With this solution, the `useEffect` should only render once, however if you wanted to pass down the socket, you can use `useRef` instead of `useEffect` since it does not re-render and works just like a normal variable.

2. **Use Custom Window Dispatch Event Hook**

I understand that you are trying to have clean code here, so maybe the alternatives is using EventTarget.dispatchEvent() browser API, this method is the one i usually going with.

With this you just need to create custom hooks to emit/listen the data, here's mine:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const  handler = ((event: CustomEvent<CustomEventDetail>) => {
        if (event.detail.emitId === id) return;
        setData(event.detail.data);

    }) as  EventListener;

    window.addEventListener(eventName, handler);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener(eventName, handler);
    };
}, [eventName, id]);
  
const  emit = (data: T) => {
    const  customEvent = new  CustomEvent<CustomEventDetail>(eventName, {
        detail: {
            emitId:  id,
            data:  data,
        },
    });

    setData(data);
    window.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
};
```

3. **Create Validator in the `useEffect`**

Maybe the last thing you wanted to try is using a validator

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
        if (currentMessage !== data.message) {
            setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
            setCurrentMessage("");
        }
    });
}, [socket]);
```

however, i don't know if it would works on don`t

---

Also for notes, don't forget to use return on the `useEffect`, so the function inside it wouldn't called multiple times because of component re-rendering, such as

```
const handler = () =>  {}
socket.on("receive_message", handler);

return () => {
    socket.off("receive_message", handler);
}
```

Hope my comments give you a solution, let me know if anything above is works for you!

Answer (score -1):

Why you are passing receive_message socket listener to the useEffect? did you tried without using useEffect

```
socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
      setCurrentMessage("");
});
```

Comment: Yes sir, I even tried without useEffect.It still displays an infinite loop.

Comment: Could you try this: 

change -  
   onClick={() => sendMessage()}  from  onClick={sendMessage}

Comment: No effect sir!!!